# Relation 1-to-many in MVC-5 with

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, webshop

I am trying to make the history of buys in a webshop project, I want the class History to have the product from the cart, I never did a relation ship many-to-one (I think is the most apropriated for the stiuation), what do you think about it?

```
    public class Clothes
        {
            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }


            public ClothesType Type { get; set; }

            public int Amount { get; set; }

            [Range(10, 150)]
            public double Price { get; set; }

            public string ImagePath { get; set; }

            public virtual History historyID { get; set; }
        }

public class History
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int historyID { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public DateTime ShipDate { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Clothes> HistClothes { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Your naming seems confusing. One `History` (what is that) has many "Clotheses"? A single class with a plural name seems strange...

Answer (score 0):

Naming conventions! The following code goes well if you want a history to have many clothes and a clothe to have only one history wich doesn't really make sense:

```
[Table("Clothes")]
public class Clothe
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ClothesType Type { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }
        [Range(10, 150)]
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
        public History historyID { get; set; } 
    }

public class History
{
    [Key]
    public int historyID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public DateTime ShipDate { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Clothe> ClothesHistory { get; set; }

    public History()
    {
        ClothesHistory = new List<Clothe>();
    }
}
```

This code instead goes well if you want to have a many history for the same clothe and a single clothe per history :

```
[Table("Clothes")]
public class Clothe
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ClothesType Type { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }
        [Range(10, 150)]
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
        public ICollection<History> Histories { get; set; } 

        public History()
        {
            Histories = new List<History>();
        }
    }

public class History
{
    [Key]
    public int historyID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public DateTime ShipDate { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Clothe RelatedClothe { get; set; }
}
```